# Setting up of Linux Server for web applications (Apache)

Tags: linux

Hi is there anyone out there that could tell me how to set up a Linux server (running CetOS 6)
to host some web apps? I want to be able to deploy to the server and update the apps by a re-deploy.
Thanks
Will

Comment: I'm a complete novice to this area and some times you can be looking so hard for information that you become blind to the obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably start from here:

http://www.lifelinux.com/how-to-setup-a-lamp-server-on-centos-6-0/

Answer (score 0):

The [LAMP software package](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) was created for exactly that purpose. It comes with all software and installation/setup instructions you could ever need. Look at the external links in the referenced Wikipedia page.